# QLabel load image, adjust size

Tags: python, image, qt

I am loading images in my GUI. I am using a QLabel for that pourpose like this:

```
self.myImage = QImage(os.path.join(folder,'samples0093.png'))
self.labelImage = QLabel()
self.labelImage.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
self.labelImage.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(self.myImage))
self.gridLayout_8.addWidget(self.labelImage)
```

The problem is that the image does not adjust to the gridLayour, it is showed as big as it is. And it is much bigger than the space for the layout.

How can I force the image to adjust to a given with and height?

Comment: Consider using `QLabel::setScaledContents(true)` for your label to adjust the image size to the size of the label.

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I have made my comment the answer as it solved the initial issue.*

Consider using `scaledContents` property and set it to `true` with `QLabel::setScaledContents()` function for your label to adjust containing image size to the size of the label.

Answer (score 0):

How can I force the image to adjust to a given with and height?

```
pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(self.myImage)
QtGui.QImage(pixmap).scaled(theWith,thHeight, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
```

Comment: thanks djangoliv, I will give this a try too, however the solution from vahancho works too :)

Answer (score 0):

I was making an application and it landed here, here's an example that worked for me

```
qrcode_img = QLabel(mainWindow)
qrcode_img.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255,255,255);")
qrcode_img.resize(300, 300)
qrcode_img.move(0,0)
qrcode_img.setPixmap(QPixmap("./src/imagem/qrcode.png").scaled(300,300))
```